# Turkish char with ESCPOS library don't work

Tags: javascript, escpos

I try to use this library : https://github.com/song940/node-escpos for print text with AURES ODP444

That's work fine but when i try to print turkish char like below i have wrong character on the paper ..

> Ç Ğ I İ Ö Ş Ü ü ş ö i ı ğ ç Â â î Î Û û

I try to encode with latin5 / ISO-8859-9 but don't work too ..

```
const escpos = require('escpos')
escpos.SerialPort = require('escpos-serialport')
const options = { encoding: "iso-8859-9" }
const device = new escpos.SerialPort('COM4')
const printer = new escpos.Printer(device, options)

device.open((error) => {
printer.font('a')
.size(0.75,0.75)
.text("Marvın")
.feed()
.close()
})
```

The result of this is **Marv²n**

Someone can help me please ?
Thank you.

Comment: Please try using tools such as the printer's hexadecimal dump mode/line monitor/protocol analyzer to check the contents of the data being sent to the printer.

Comment: How i can see what's send to the printer ?

Comment: It's easiest if you can see the print commands even if you put the printer in hexadecimal dump mode. However, that often doesn't work, and it depends on the connection method of your printer. A network monitor such as sniffer can be considered if connected via Ethernet, a serial line monitor if connected via DSUB9 serial, or a USB protocol analyzer if connected via USB.

Comment: In my case, the printer is in serial port, so i can use software like this https://www.virtual-serial-port.org/fr/articles/how-to-monitor-serial-port/ ?

Comment: Hardware products are less likely to be difficult to install and configure, but software should be fine for commercial products.

Answer (score 1):

For someone who want the answer (for ODP333/ODP444)

If you want change encodage, download utility software from support website, connect to your printer and change code page (For turkish it's cp857) and don't forget in your code to encode in cp857.

```
const options = { encoding: "cp857" }
```

http://aures-support.com/DATA/Doc/PRINTER/CONFIGURATION-MANUALTHERMAL-PRINTER_AURES.pdf

Thanks all for your help !